# How to add a button with a link that comes from an object property value in a foor loop?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a code that prints out some information and I am trying to make a button for every time that for loop iterats and that if someone clicks on it gets redirected to another website to show more information.

For example imagine you open a website and you have a list of countries on the left side. When you click on USA a bunch of info shows up about all of USA's different cities, and you can click on a button that says "show more information" which redirects you to another website which shows more info about that city.

I don't want jQuery solutions because I am new to JavaScript.

Here's my code

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {

            var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("newside").innerHTML = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.something.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("newside").innerHTML += "<h3>" + data.something[i].somethingagain + "</h3>" 
               //here i want a button to be created that redirects somewhere before the next iteration;
```

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: Can you add the data that's returned from the AJAX call?

Comment: just use `.innerHTML` to create a button/link the same way you used to create `h3` and other information: `.innerHTML += '<a href="'+data.infoLink+'">More Info!</a>'`;

Comment: @Prerak sola, read whole question please and with code. i want a button to be created in foor loop with each iteration that i could assigne it a link which comes from the object property

Comment: I read it and it only says what you want. Not what's the issue that you are facing in your attempt. If you need some free code, this is not the place. Pease see [ask].

Comment: @MarceloTheWizzardCoder that worked thank you!